# What's the significance of 41 Years?

Tags: timestamp, gaming

In a popular online video game (World of Warcraft) there's a friends list displaying how long since each friend is online. Recently, there's been a bug where many friends show as being offline for 41 Years. Is there any significance to this number? I checked if it matched a max int timestamp, but no suck luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Computer time is often measured from Jan 1 1970 (know as "the epoch").  It's been 40.5 years since then, rounded up to 41.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: So essentially, the "LastOnlineTime" for some users was set to DateTime.Minimum

Comment: http://xkcd.com/376/

Comment: Thanks - seems obvious now you say it! I was looking at all sorts of significant numbers represented as a timestamp, but didn't think of comparing the current date! My guess is they don't have a default value, so for anyone who hasn't been seen online at all, it would default to 0, or the epoch itself.